# The difference between split and re. split

Tags: regex, python-3.x, split

Why the output of second code not printing only 12?

```
import re
print(re.split('\d+','On 12th feb 2016, at 11:02 A.M',1))


from re import split
print(split('\d+','On 12th feb 2016, at 11:02 A.M'))


['On ', 'th Jan ', ', at ', ':', ' AM']

['On ', 'th Jan 2016, at 11:02 AM']
```

Comment: They're *both* `re.split`. Why did you expect that passing another argument to `re.split` *wouldn't* change the output?

Answer (score 0):

In your first call to split you are providing an extra parameter '1' which tell the regex engine to only take one split at most. That's why you obtain only one split.

In your second call to split every possible split is accomplished.